# How do I limit the input of scanf to integers and floats (numbers in general)

Tags: c, scanf, fflush

I am curently learning C Programming in University and I got the task to write a program witch puts out the interception points with 0 / x-axis of any function ax^2+bx+c.

In order to make sure that the input is correct (int, float, etc.) I run the following `while` loop. Prior to that `a` is definded as a double.

```
printf("Input for a=");

while (scanf("%lf", &a) == 0)
{
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    printf("Incorrect Input! New Input needed.\n"); 
    printf("a=");
}
```

I am aware that the `fflush(stdin)` operator only clears the buffer when a second input function occurs and therefore the `fflush` inside the loop does not clear the buffer and therefore the condition of the loop is always true and thus I created an infinite loop.

My professor also forbids the use of `goto`, which is why I am here, because I can't come up with a reasonable solution that solves this problem.
I also tried and failed with:

```
do
{
    printf("\nInput for a= ");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
}

while (isdigit(a));
{
    printf("Thank you.\n");
}
```

With this arrangement I get the failure notification: `Expression c >= -1 && <= 255`. I guess this has to do with false variable definition (double, digit) or such.

However my original question was whether there is an elegant solution to this problem or at least any solution.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour, don't do it.

Comment: In case you are interested in the whole program as of now: 
https://pastebin.com/0ELkCiS7

Comment: Before doing anything else, please [indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) your program properly. This is is very important, not so much for us but rather four _you_.

Comment: Are you asking how to take input and distinguish between an `int` and `float` with the same `scanf` statement? Or, are you simply wanting to limit input to one or the other? In either case it is better to enclose the block in a continual loop, e.g. `for (;;) { int rtn = scanf (...); ... }` where you validate the return (`rtn`) and if the input is good, simply `break;`. Why? `scanf` can return `0` or `EOF` on failure and controlling the loop with `== 0` will fail to detect `EOF`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Im am asking how to distinguish between all numbers and every other possible input for scanf.
I want the scanf function to only assign the input value to the variable if the input is correct.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  Thank you, I may work on that :)

Comment: @Jabberwocky what alternatives are there for fflush?

Comment: Most `scanf` formats ignore leading whitespace anyway if that is the purpose of trying to flush the input. A noteable exception is `"%c"` where adding a space before `" %c"` will cause whitespace to be filtered. But if th input was say `"a"` then you'll need to flush the buffer. Note: it is **vital** to check the return value from `scanf` function family (number of items scanned).

Comment: ... note too that you call `scanf` twice in the loop, what is that for?

Comment: @WeatherVane I thought I could "override" the variable a with another scanf input..

Comment: Once you have scanned it it has gone. Reading a line with `fgets` is more flexible. If one `sscanf` doesn't work, you can try again with another. And it is easy to just dump that line and read another one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lukas, I'm still not 100% clear and your:

> *"Im am asking how to distinguish between all numbers and every other possible input for scanf."*

`scanf` can provide conversion to a single given type based on the *conversion specifier* used, so you can't read both `int` and `float` with the same `scanf` statement and a single conversion specifier. (now you can read a line with, e.g. `fgets` and then use alternate `sscanf` statements and check the remaining characters to do that)

That said, I think I understand what you are asking and can answer both the `fflush` and read of a value questions.

To begin, when using `scanf` you must **check the return** and handle three-cases. (1) `EOF`, the user cancels input with a <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows); (2) a *matching* or *input* failure occurs resulting in a return of less than the number of *conversion specifiers* used; and finally (3) the good input case (where you impose any additional checks you have, e.g. positive, less than `100`, etc..)

While `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior on most systems, there are a number of implementations that allow it. (primarily windows, but Linux allows it for *seekable* stream, e.g. a file redirected on `stdin`) Bottom line, it isn't portable without caveats, so it's best to provide a simple equivalent with `getchar()`, e.g.

```
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

As for `scanf`, as I mentioned in the comment, it is far easier to enclose the `scanf` call within an infinite loop which you only break when the input satisfies all your constraints. A simple example requiring integer input would be:

```
int getint (int *value, const char *prompt)
{
    /* loop continually until good input or canceled */
    for (;;) {
        int rtn;
        fputs (prompt, stdout);     /* display prompt */
        rtn = scanf ("%d", value);

        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* user generated manual EOF */
            fputs ("<user canceled input>\n", stderr);
            return 0;
        }
        empty_stdin();  /* all other cases - empty input buffer */
        if (rtn == 1)   /* good input, break */
            break;
        /* otherwise matching failure */
        fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
    }
    return *value;  /* value also availale through pointer */
}
```

Putting it altogether in a simple example, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int getint (int *value, const char *prompt)
{
    /* loop continually until good input or canceled */
    for (;;) {
        int rtn;
        fputs (prompt, stdout);     /* display prompt */
        rtn = scanf ("%d", value);

        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* user generated manual EOF */
            fputs ("<user canceled input>\n", stderr);
            return 0;
        }
        empty_stdin();  /* all other cases - empty input buffer */
        if (rtn == 1)   /* good input, break */
            break;
        /* otherwise matching failure */
        fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
    }
    return *value;  /* value also availale through pointer */
}

int main (void) {

    int v,
        i = getint (&v, "enter integer value: ");

    if (i)
        printf ("\ninteger: %d\n", v);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Where you can now do your best to break any input routine you write. If you find a problem, go fix it and try to break it again.

The code above allows for fairly robust input of any one given type of value, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/scanfint
enter integer value: no
  error: invalid integer input.
enter integer value: apples, banannas, and pears
  error: invalid integer input.
enter integer value: 21

integer: 21
```

Look things over and let me know if your question was slightly different, or if you have further questions about the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed awnser! I think this will solve my problem. If I still cant solve it I may come back.. Thanks anyways!

Comment: 2 ideas: A `fflush(stdout);` between `fputs (prompt, stdout);`  `rtn = scanf ("%d", value);` makes certain prompt is seen before input. When `empty_stdin();` returns due to `ferror()`, I'd expect a return from `getint()` like in `if (rtn == EOF)`, but that is a subtle point.

Comment: I was not suggesting  `empty_stdin()` between `fputs (prompt, stdout);` `rtn = scanf ("%d", value);`.  I was suggesting `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. I read it in a hurry and thought you have used a shorthand for flushing `stdin`, yes flushing `stdout` there makes sense. However, since `scanf` is an input function that would force a flush of `stdout` at that point. Wouldn't it be repetitive there?